# How to repair a torn DAT tape?

Tags: tape

My question is:
How to fix a DAT tape that is broken/torn in two parts ?
Are there specialists that know how to do that ? What kind of professional s could have this skill ?

I don't mind if I lose a few seconds or minutes of sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the break is at the beginning (or end) it might be easier to simply discard the short piece and attach the tape to the nearest hub. Some people over at TaperSection.com have shown how to do it with old cassette splicing tape but then carefully trimming the excess (because cassette tape is wider than DAT tape).

But unless you have some current good (i.e. not dried out decades old) special splicing tape and extreme patience it may be hazardous to the equipment to put the rotating heads in jeopardy by kludging a bodged splice with ordinary sticky tape.

If the contents of the tape are REALLY that valuable, find an expert and prepare to pay. Otherwise you are putting the DAT machine at significant risk of permanent, irreparable damage from a bad splice job.

Ref: http://taperssection.com/index.php?topic=140812.0

Answer (score 1):

Cut properly and under magnetic tape (non magnetic area). You can stick with transparent thin tape.  We used to do this with audio and video tapes.

Comment: What do you mean by "Under Magnaic Tape" ? I don't understand